# Mantis integration into Maven

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, bug-tracking, mantis

Apart from the [maven-changes-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changes-plugin/usage.html),
does it exist a Maven plugin for Mantis integration ?
The idea would be to connect to the [Mantis SOAP API](http://www.mantisbt.org/wiki/doku.php/mantisbt%3afaq#does_mantisbt_provide_a_webservice_interface) to provide more interaction with MantisBT.
For example you could :

- create an issue
- create a project
- create a version of a project
- etc.

A Java API already exist to provide a client web service with Mantis : **[biz.futureware.mantis:mantis-axis-soap-client](http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22biz.futureware.mantis%22%20AND%20a%3A%22mantis-axis-soap-client%22)**.

Other ways which provide [Mantis Integration](http://www.mantisbt.org/wiki/doku.php/mantisbt%3afaq#integration).

Comment: What kind of integration do you need apart from the URL templates etc. ?

Comment: @khmarbaise The list of features provided by the Mantis SOAP API can be found [there](http://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/api/soap/mantisconnect.php).  One of the use cases I can think about would be to add a version to a project managed by Mantis. This could be invoked during a release like in `mvn release:prepare release:perform mantis:addProjectVersion`.

Comment: The simplest solution is to use the releaseVersion as paraemter mvn -DreleaseVersion=WhatEverVersion release:prepare release:perform

Comment: Yes, it would be practical to cut the `-SNAPSHOT` of the version. But it would be nice if it could also work _outside_ of a release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually started to develop a plugin, named [**mantis-maven-plugin**](https://github.com/ghusta/mantis-maven-plugin), hosted on GitHub.

This plugin connects Maven to the Mantis SOAP API.
Up to now, this plugin enables to :

1. **add-project-version** : Create a project's version
2. **display-project-versions** : Displays the versions of a project
3. **display-version** : Displays the version of Mantis server

If someone wants to contribute, don't hesitate to clone the project : https://github.com/ghusta/mantis-maven-plugin.